Querying 3 tables that return 32 records took 11 seconds. How to improve query?
I am doing a database query using PHP and wordpress.
In the query below, it's taking too long to return the results.
(32 total, Query took 11.4666 seconds.)
The database server is returning a timeout error when the result count is more than 500.
Is there a better way I can query 3 tables?
The schema is like this:
notes table
date_created
date_modified
note_author
note_text
contact_id
usermeta table
user_id
meta_key
meta_value
users
ID (this is user_id in usermeta table)
user_email
SELECT note.date_created as date_created,
 note.date_modified as date_modified,
 firstname.meta_value as first_name, 
 lastname.meta_value as last_name,
 useremail.user_email as email,
 note.note_author as author,
 note.note_text as note,
 userid.user_id 
FROM `notes` as note 
LEFT JOIN usermeta AS userid 
 ON note.contact_id = userid.meta_value 
LEFT JOIN users as useremail 
 ON userid.user_id = useremail.ID 
LEFT JOIN usermeta AS firstname 
 ON userid.user_id = firstname.user_id 
LEFT JOIN usermeta AS lastname
 ON userid.user_id = lastname.user_id 
WHERE userid.meta_key = 'activecampaign_contact_id'
 AND firstname.meta_key = 'first_name' 
 AND lastname.meta_key = 'last_name' 
 AND note.contact_id = 80426;

I would like to improve the performance of the query so it can handle thousands of records.
Right now my query is returning timeout error when the result exceeds 500.

pls post the execution plan

You are joining usermeta three times. As far as I can tell you can pull that information out of a single join with that table.

To obtain the execution plan, use an EXPLAIN.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.3/en/using-explain.html

This probably can be resolved by creating some appropriate indexes. Please [edit] your question to show us the output of SHOW CREATE TABLE for each relevant table.

EAV is a difficult schema patter to optimize.
The tables sem to be over-normalized.  (No need to split parts of a name across multiple tables.)
These composite indexes will help some.
firstname:  INDEX(meta_key, user_id,  meta_value)
lastname:  INDEX(meta_key, user_id,  meta_value)
userid:  INDEX(meta_key, meta_value,  user_id)

If meta_value is TEXT, leave it out of the index.
If note.contact_id is a VARCHAR, quote `'80426'.

If this really is WordPress, see https://wordpress.org/plugins/index-wp-mysql-for-speed/
